# Disrupted transfer from AS400 to pure-ftpd on Ubuntu

Tags: ftp, ibm-midrange

We have an FTP job that runs between an AS400 and pure-ftpd on Ubuntu that's worked for two years. The AS400 (in a remote shop) sends three files.

Recently, it only gets the first of the three done, and then stalls.

AS400 log:

```
> put foo
229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||45944|)
150 Accepted data connection
226-File successfully transferred
226 [speed data]
Enter an FTP subcommand
> put bar
229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||5743|)
No response from remote host; all connections closed.
Enter an FTP subcommand.
> put baz
You must first open a connection.
```

pure-ftpd log:

```
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (?@iseries.touro.edu) [INFO] New connection from iseries.touro.edu
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (?@iseries.touro.edu) [DEBUG] Command [user] [itload]
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (?@iseries.touro.edu) [DEBUG] Command [pass] [<*>]
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (?@iseries.touro.edu) [INFO] itload is now logged in
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (itload@iseries.touro.edu) [DEBUG] Command [syst] []
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (itload@iseries.touro.edu) [DEBUG] Command [epsv] []
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (itload@iseries.touro.edu) [DEBUG] Command [stor] [foo]
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (itload@iseries.touro.edu) [NOTICE] /path/to//foo uploaded  (4394019 bytes, 32219.83KB/sec)
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (itload@iseries.touro.edu) [DEBUG] Command [epsv] []
Oct 25 15:59:39 lb-serv3 pure-ftpd: (itload@iseries.touro.edu) [DEBUG] Command [stor] [bar]
```

Any wisdom? Many thanks!

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that sometimes a zero-length file of the correct name has been created in the correct directory.

Comment: Words of wisdom? Only two -- "What Changed?"

Comment: @voretaq7 - yeah, seriously. the AS400 shop claims nothing. I can't find any changes in our FTP config.

Comment: What about networking changes? Any routers, switches changed recently? If you sniff the network, do you see anything weird?

Comment: How big is the file / how long is the transfer?  Is there a firewall in between that may be closing the command channel due to a timeout?

Comment: It's supposed to be about 1.5M, smaller than the successfully transferred file

Answer (score 1):

The AS400 shop altered their script, and that fixed the problem. They are not aware of anything that changed that would have caused the problem. Thanks commenters!